# different values of string and string.c_str()

Tags: c++, string, sockets, network-programming

i'm trying to send a file through the network using c++. first of all, i read my file and buffer it into a string and then i convert my string to c_str() and send it by my socket class

i have a problem with when i send my data, it doesn't output correctly. i wrote the following code to check that and i realize that the value of my string and string.c_str() is different from each other

```
ifstream source(path.c_str(), ios::binary);   
ostringstream out;
out << source.rdbuf();

string msg = out.str();

source.close();

cout << "msg: " << msg << endl;
printf("sent - %s\n", message.c_str());
```

the result of this two line is different. "cout" prints my file's characters but printf just print 3 characters

why this happen?

thanks a lot your help

Comment: We cannot guess what whats wrong, edit your question and add more code sample, like socket writing and file reading.

Comment: Is `msg` just printable characters, or are you embedding a more complex structure that may also have nulls and such?  Because if the file you are reading in is more than just text, I'd probably use something other than a std::string to store it in (e.g. `vector<char>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the string contains embedded zero '\0' after the third character.